# Check if a thread is running from the "mother" class

Tags: android, sqlite

In my Main Activity, I have a Thread that is doing *alot* of stuff, including adding some records to a database. In my second activity, which inherit from the Main Activity, I want to do a query to my database. But I need to check if the first thread in the Main Activity is finished, what I've done so far is:

```
public class History extends Main {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    if(!(MainThread.isAlive())) {
            getFromDatabase();
    }
}
}
```

This is my `getFromDatabase()` method

```
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please Wait",
                "Getting cases from database", false);

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
```

which will call this run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {

    ArrayList<Case> c = db1.getAllCases();
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = c;
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message m) {
        pd.dismiss();
        list = (ArrayList<Case>) m.obj;
        tempList = getCaseNumberToTempList(list);
        tempCaseList = createTempList(list);

        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(History.this, list));
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
};
```

But if I do so, the following line of code will crash my application, it will give a `NullPointerException`:

```
if(!(MainThread.isAlive())) {
            getFromDatabase();
    }
```

How can I be sure that that the first thread is finished with all the work before I query the database from my history activity?

Comment: Oh my god, I know that I can use an asyncTask for this. But that is **NOT** the question here. Flagging your comment.

Comment: Well feel free, but really, what is your reason for not using asynctask? db, web and other kinds of transferences is just what asynctask is made for. When you choose to make a thread, and thereafter need functionality already implemented in ASyncTask, and you not explaining why you have chosen not to use such tool. That should make it a perfectly fine comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `Thread` in the `getFromDatabase()` method a static class level variable, write a static get method for it in your `Activity`, and check for `isAlive()` in your child `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply using a semaphore variable that you modify from the thread once it has reached a certain state?